# MersenneTwister generator

Tags: java, random, apache-commons-math

I am trying to generate Mersenne Twister generator but I always have this massage "MersenneTwister cannot be resolved to a type" 
This is my code

```
public class RandomVariable
{
  /** Initialize Mersenne Twister generator. */

  private static MersenneTwister rnd  = new MersenneTwister();

  /** Generate a uniformly distributed random number between 0 and 1.
   *
   *  @return      A double between 0 and 1.
   *
   *  </p>
   */

  public static double rand()
  {
    return rnd.nextDouble();
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to `import` `MersenneTwister`.

Comment: I already import java.util.Random; I thought this would be enough How I can import MersenneTwister

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/MersenneTwister.html) library in your Java projects classpath and add the following import line in your source code:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.random.MersenneTwister;
```